# Computing Eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the following matrix :

$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S} = \left(
\begin{array} {cc}
.0144 & .0117\\
.0117 & .01466
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$

I found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=.026$ and $\lambda_2=.002$. Then I tried to find the eigenvectors.

$$\mathbf{S}\mathbf{x}=\lambda_1\mathbf{x}$$
or

$$.0144x_1+.0117x_2=.026x_1$$
$$.0117x_1+.0146x_2=.026x_2$$

From the first equation , $.0117x_2=.0116x_1$

The result is

for $\lambda_1=.026$,  $\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x_1} = \left(
\begin{array} {c}
.704\\
.710
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$

and for $\lambda_2=.002$,  $\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x_2} = \left(
\begin{array} {c}
-.710\\
.704
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$

I suppose those are normalizing eigenvectors but don't come up with the results.  How can I compute the eigenvector ?

Comment: Who is "they" in your last sentence?

Comment: @5xum Please see the edit.

Comment: If you are working with $0.26$ as the eigenvalue, you will make large mistakes because of numeric errors...

Comment: @5xum It is  $.026$ , not $.26$.

Comment: OK, but my point stays. The thing with eigenvalues is that if you are calculating them by hand, you need to use exact values, not numeric approximations.

Comment: simply: take $\dfrac{{\mathbf x}_i}{||{\mathbf x}_i||}$ and they still are eigen

Comment: @janmarqz But I couldn't calculate $\mathbf {x_i}$.

Comment: i am talking of your ${\mathbf x}_1$ and ${\mathbf x}_2$

Comment: after the equation  $.0117x_2=.0116x_1$, I don't know how is to proceed.

Comment: choose any $x_2$ and you will get a $x_1$

Comment: also use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7B.0144%2C.0117%7D%2C%7B.0117%2C.01466%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

From your equation (note that the system is underdetermined, so you should get an infinite number of solutions):
$$.0117x_2=.0116x_1$$
you can get an eigenvector by setting $x_1$ and solving for $x_2$. If you set $x_1 = 1$ you get:
$$x_2 = \frac{.0116}{.0117} = \frac{116}{117}$$
so $$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{116}{117} \end{pmatrix}$$ should be an eigenvector for $S$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. You will see that this is not quite right, if you compare the vectors $Av_1$ and $\lambda_1v_1$. This is because you have too few decimals in your $\lambda_1$.

The exact eigenvalues for your given matrix are:
$$\lambda_1 = \frac{1453 + 13\sqrt{8101}}{100000}$$
$$\lambda_2 = \frac{1453 - 13\sqrt{8101}}{100000}.$$

If you do the calculations with the exact value for $\lambda_1$, you get the equation
$$.0144x_1+.0117x_2=\lambda_1x_1$$
which simplies to:
$$.0117x_2 = (\lambda_1 - .0144)x_1.$$
Set $x_1 = 1$ and solve for $x_2$:
$$x_2 = \frac{\lambda_1 - .0144}{.0117} = \frac{\frac{1453+13 \sqrt{8101}}{100000} - .0144}{.0177} = \frac{1}{90} \left(1+\sqrt{8101}\right)$$
and so
$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{90} \left(1+\sqrt{8101}\right)\end{pmatrix}$$
is your sought after eigenvector.

Note that the difference between the values for $x_2$ calculated by approximate values and exact values is quite large, approximately $.0197$.

A useful trick here is to using fractional numbers all the time, never decimal ones. You can e.g. write S as:
$$S = \frac{1}{100000}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1440 & 1170 \\ 1170 & 1466
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: But softwares provide the eigenvectors of the problem are: for $\lambda_1=.026$,  $\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x_1} = \left(
\begin{array} {c}
.704\\
.710
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$ and for $\lambda_2=.002$,  $\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x_2} = \left(
\begin{array} {c}
-.710\\
.704
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$. How all of the softwares assume the same arbitrary value while it comes to mind to take $1$ when doing it by hand?

Comment: @ABC, note that if $x$ is an eigenvector, then $\alpha x$ is an eigenvector as well, for all scalar $\alpha \neq 0$. The software has given you a normalized eigenvector.